# IntelliJ checkstyle plugin installed from disk with "Could not determine plugin directory" error

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I just installed the checkstyle plugin from disk in IntelliJ by navigating to the jar which is just in the directory that it was downloaded to.  When I restart IntelliJ to have the plugin take effect I get the following error:

```
2:50 PM Unexpected Exception Caught
                The scan failed due to an exception: Could not determine plugin directory
                org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.exception.CheckStylePluginException: Could not determine plugin directory
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleClassLoader.getBasePath(CheckstyleClassLoader.java:173)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleClassLoader.buildClassLoader(CheckstyleClassLoader.java:94)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleClassLoader.<init>(CheckstyleClassLoader.java:69)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleProjectService$1.call(CheckstyleProjectService.java:69)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleProjectService$1.call(CheckstyleProjectService.java:64)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleProjectService.checkstyleClassLoader(CheckstyleProjectService.java:117)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.CheckstyleProjectService.getCheckstyleInstance(CheckstyleProjectService.
```

I am on IntelliJ 2018.1 and the most recent version of the checkstyle plugin.  Is it claiming it is unable to find the directory where the checkstyle plugin jar is even though I just installed it by pointing it to that directory?  Do I need to move the jar to some kind of plugins directory?  I'm following the guides I found online and they do not mention having to do anything besides what I have already done.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind.  I was pointing to a particular jar file instead of the zip file for the whole plugin.  Installing from disk and pointing to the zip file instead fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Uninstall the plugin and restart Intellij
2. Reinstall the plugin pointing to the zip file as originally downloaded from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea
3. Restart Intellij